# Using Firebase.auth.signOut() doesn't sign the user out completely

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I have been trying to build a chatting application on Android Studio using Kotlin and am trying to use Firebase Authentication (Phone) for registering users.

I need to do two things:

1. I want my app to navigate to **PhoneAuthActivity** when I click on the logout option from my *MainActivity* 's options menu.
2. I want to check if a user is logged in at **SplashActivity**. If yes then proceed to **MainActivity**. If not, go to **PhoneAuthActivity**.

For the first part, I have written the following code

**MainActivity**

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.search -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.settings -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.update -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Update Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.logout -> {
                val alert: AlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this).create()
                alert.setTitle("Logout")
                alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?")
                alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes") { dialog, which ->
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            Firebase.auth.signOut()
                        }
                    }
                    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,PhoneAuthActivity::class.java)
                    dialog.dismiss()
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No") { dialog, which ->
                dialog.dismiss()
                }
                alert.show()
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

And for the 2nd part

**SplashActivity**

```
import android.animation.Animator
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.anubhav.chatapp.databinding.ActivitySplashBinding
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySplashBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySplashBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.animationView.addAnimatorListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
            override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animator?) {
            }
            override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animator?) {
                if (Firebase.auth.currentUser != null) {
                    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                } else if (Firebase.auth.currentUser == null) {
                    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, PhoneAuthActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                }
            }
            override fun onAnimationCancel(p0: Animator?) {
            }
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animator?) {
            }

        })
    }
}
```

Now the first part works fine but when I relaunch the app I am again redirected to MainActivty but it should go to PhoneAuthActivity instead as the user is supposed to be logged out. In this instance, if I log out again, the app crashes and **user gets logged out**.

But why is it taking 2 clicks to sign out the user completely?

Comment: If you understand Java, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help, since it contains a SplashScreen. Otherwise, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) or this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8) might also help.

Comment: So you basically say that `Firebase.auth.currentUser != null` even if the user is signed out?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, this condition gets true always even after signing out. An intent for MainActivity is created instead of PhoneAuthActivity. 
However weirdly, in this case, when ultimately MainActivity does launch, and I try to sign out, the app crashes but the user gets signed out.

Comment: Have you tried to get `Firebase.auth.signOut()` outside the coroutine? Does it work that way?

Comment: Yes I have tried it outside the coroutine as well but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I have done the signOut of the user like this:

```
    FirebaseAuth user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user.signOut();
```

And for checking the user is signed in or not:

```
    FirebaseAuth user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
     

        // User is signed in
        
    } else {
        
        // User is signed out
       
    }
```

Just check again by implementing this way!

Comment: Thanks! writing the logic in this way fixed the issue. But I don't understand what difference does it make 

Previous (Not Working) ->
`if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser != null)`

Updated (Working) -> 
`val user: FirebaseUser? = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser` and then checking
`if(user != null)`

Don't they both mean the same logically?

Comment: Happy to hear that your problem is solved ,You can upvote the answer so that it can be helpful for other people also. Both may not be same as may be their is the reference to the Firebase User is needed as  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser is returning the FirebaseUser Object.